# Clickonce isn't creating an appname.exe.config.deploy file correct

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, clickonce

I am trying to publish an internal application I have developed.  I have done this multiple times before with no issues, but never with this application.

In VS2010 I go to my `TestManager` project, hit publish, and set everything up correctly.  I go to my folder and run the `setup.exe`.  Installation then fails and gives me a log file stating that it cannot find the `TestManager.exe.config.deploy` file.

When I go into the `Application Files` directory, it's true that it did not create a `TestManager.exe.config.deploy` file, but it instead created the config as `App.config.deploy`.

I have looked at my other ClickOnce installers (even installers for other projects in the same solution) and verified that it is correctly creating an `<appname>.exe.config.deploy` and not creating an `app.config.deploy`.

Why is Click-Once not creating the app.config file properly for deployment, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm not clear if this will work, but if you're having ClickOnce file deploy issues with specific files, then the first thing I check is the build action property for those files.

Using the Solution Explorer, check that the App.Config's build action is still "None".

If it were listed as "Content", this might lead to the file being deployed with it's original name (rather than the prefixed name) as you mentioned.

NOTE: Other config files should be marked as Content in order to ensure they end up in the deploy folder.

Comment: That was it!  It was set as "Content" and not "None".

Comment: Thank you, That was exactly the case!